# My mansory.js layout is adding unexpected space between images

Tags: css

So I am using this codepen:

https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/bdgRzg

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }


/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  background: #DDD;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 33.333%;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

However my images are lining up like this:

[image]

I think it's because of other styles because I am using a theme. What CSS rule can I add so that the images come after each other like in the demo?

Comment: Why are you ignoring the error in the console. It tells you that `$` is not defined (So something is wrong with jQuery)

Comment: Looks like you don't have jQuery library added to your page so it does not instantiate the masonry library. Look at the error saying "... $ is not defined" in your browser console.

Comment: I am using a jQuery libary...

Comment: Yes, but did you include it before mansory.js? You can inspect the elements in the codepen you added and see that the script added styles like `style="position: absolute; left: 66.665%; top: 943.469px;"` which are not present in your screenshot

Comment: Thankyou that solved it @AlonEitan, seriously that I overlooked that. I have been looking at this for 2 hours